# Make scrollable resultset in queryforobject method in jdbctemplate

Tags: java, resultset, jdbctemplate, scrollable

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate in my project and I need to make a resultset scrollable for my mappers.
I have done it for getAll() method and it looks like next:

```
@Override
public List<T> getAll() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(getPreparedStatementCreator(getQueryToGetAll()), mapper);
}

private PreparedStatementCreator getPreparedStatementCreator(String query) {
    return connection -> connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
}
```

It works, as JdbcTemplate has next method:

```
public <T> List<T> query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

So, I have implemented PreparedStatementCreator as the first parameter and put mapper as the second.

Now I need to make getById() method, but I haven't found a suitable method in the JdbcTemplate with PreparedStatementCreator and mapper as a parameter.

This my  getById() method:

```
@Override
public Optional<T> getById(Integer id) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getQueryToGetById(), mapper, id));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

How can I make a scrollable resultset for it?